# How to fix : java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException from spark UDF function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have a the following dataframe : let's say DF1 as

```
root
 |-- VARIANTS: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VARIANT_ID: long (nullable = false)
 |-- CASE_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- APP_ID: integer (nullable = false)
```

Where Variants (string) look like :

> Activity_1,Activity_2,Activity_2,Activity_3,Activity_5...

Am trying to get a new column like

Variants_stats as (per Row) :

> Activity_1:1, Activity_2:2, Activity_3:1, Activity_5:1

The approach i have took so far is :
1) Create an UDF :

```scala
val countActivityFrequences = udf((value: String) => value.split(",").map(_.trim).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length).map{case (k, v) => k + ":" + v}.mkString(","))
val dfNew = df1.withColumn("Variants_stats", countActivityFrequences($"VARIANTS"))
```

It seems to be ok (at least spark doesn't complain), until i try to do any SQL or dfNew.show(false) call, which always give me back :

```java
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -84
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
    at java.lang.Class.getSimpleBinaryName(Class.java:1448)
    at java.lang.Class.getSimpleName(Class.java:1309)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.udfErrorMessage$lzycompute(ScalaUDF.scala:1055)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.udfErrorMessage(ScalaUDF.scala:1054)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.doGenCode(ScalaUDF.scala:1006)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:105)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
```

I can't figure out what am doing wrong here ?

Am using Spark 2.1+

To reproduce :

```scala
val items = List(
    "A_001,A_002,A_010,A_0200,A_0201,A_0201,A_0202,A_0206,A_0207,A_0208,A_0208,A_0209,A_070,A_071,A_072,A_073,A_073,A_074",
    "A_001,A_002,A_010,A_0201,A_0201,A_0201,A_0202,A_0206,A_0207,A_0208,A_0208,A_0209,A_070,A_071,A_072,A_073,A_073,A_073")
val df = sc.parallelize(items).toDF("VARIANTS")
df.show(false)
df.printSchema

// create UDF function
val countActivityFrequences = udf((value: String) => value.split(",").map(_.trim).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length).map{case (k, v) => k + ":" + v}.mkString(","))
// Apply UDF against our little DF
var dfNew = df.withColumn("Variants_stats", countActivityFrequences($"VARIANTS"))
dfNew.printSchema
// Error Thrown : (either Malforned class name, or java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException )
dfNew.show(false)
```

**Update** :

The issue was only appearing in our AWS EMR environment, under zeppelin.
Restarting the interpreter made it work.

Comment: Works fine for me in *Spark 2.4.0*.

Comment: When i use the spark-shell on my laptop it works. but it fails on zeppelin running on AWS EMR. This may implies an environment issue.